# JSON selector for jq

Tags: json, jq, export-to-csv

I would like to get a CSV file from the [Mozilla CommonVoice JSON statistics](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/common-voice/cv-dataset/main/datasets/cv-corpus-10.0-2022-07-04.json). It looks like this:

```json
{
  ...,
  "locales": {
    "en": {
      ...,
      "validHrs": 2275.28
    },
    "fa": {
      ...,
      "validHrs": 327.14
    },
  }
}
```

I manage to get the value of `validHrs` for a single language:

```bash
jq ".locales.en.validHrs" cv-corpus-10.0-2022-07-04.json
```

```
2275.28
```

```bash
jq ".locales.fa.validHrs" cv-corpus-10.0-2022-07-04.json
```

```
327.14
```

But not for all. Goal is a CSV with:

```
en,2275.28
fa,327.14
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```bash
cat cv-corpus-10.0-2022-07-04.json| jq -r '.locales | keys[] as $k | "\($k),\(.[$k] | .validHrs)"'
```

The output looks like:

```
ab,59.71
ar,87.747
as,2.14
ast,0
az,0.12
ba,256.46
bas,2.04
be,1089.38
bg,9.15
bn,61.6
br,9.56
ca,1389.83
...
```

Comment: `jq -r '.locales | keys[] as $k | [ $k, ( .[$k] | .validHrs ) ] | @csv'` would be better

Comment: If the order of the CSV rows is not important, or if it should reflect the input, then `keys_unsorted` should be considered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_entries` which will give you each `key, value` pair:

```
$ jq -r '.locales | to_entries[] | "\(.key),\(.value.validHrs)"' cv.json 
en,2275.28
fa,327.14
fr,868.35
es,411.31
sl,10.09
kab,552.81
[...]
```

Comment: In general, it is safer to use `@csv` to be sure the output is valid as CSV. It's also easier on the eyes :-)